# Does IPS mean 8 bits per color

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, colors

I just ordered an [MSI GT72VR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IO9Y3RO) which has an NVIDIA GTX 1060 and states that is has an IPS display.

When I first fired it up, I noticed really bad gradient banding. Instead of many colors, most gradients would only have about 3. [Here](https://www.amazon.com/review/R97LSI4UIJGOL/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B01IO9Y3RO&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=541966&store=pc) is a review with pictures of the same problem.

After searching online, I found a workaround where you could trick the NVIDIA drivers into setting the resolution to 1920x1080x100Hz (as opposed to 60Hz default) which would allow you to set the colors to 6bpc (bits per color) instead of 8bpc. Which seems odd, because when I run HWInfo on the panel, it states that it can support 8bpc.

Once changed, the display seemed to resolve most of its issues and looks similar to other displays I have. (It's close enough that I'm not sure whether I still see a problem or whether its all in my head). However, I believe that the monitor is using 6bpc with dithering to approximate full 8bpc. As I have researched panels in general, it seems like a large percentage of panels favor speed over color and only support 6bpc and use dithering.

So I am trying to decide if I should return the computer, so to my questions:

1. If they advertise an IPS monitor, should it be supporting full 8bpc?
2. If not, is the problem likely that the manufacturer messed up and the panel should really be reporting to the NVIDIA drivers that it supports only 6bpc?
3. If the panel does support only 6bpc, is there another way I can find out? Is my workaround sufficient, or do I have a sup par display?

Comment: IMO, what you are looking at (at least in that amazon review) is a blown-out (uncalibrated) monitor gamma and brightness, rather than a bit-depth representation. Try going through a proper calibration and see if that resolves the issue. Also, I do not *think* there is a 1:1 correspondence between 8-bit rgb and n-bit lcd representations

Comment: 1) IPS says nothing about bpc. 2) Dithering does not change the bpc value. 3) Panels themselves cannot favour speed over colour. Also, the graphics card's specs do not suggest this. 4) Even though the panel HW may handle 8 bpc, the data from the graphics card might in theory be limited to 6 bpc (would that make sense, though?). 5) MSI advertises all GT72VR to have "MSI True Color Tech visual experience", which is advertised as "closse to 100% sRGB". Behind that is a calibration process. Real panels with affordable price don't have sRGB so you'd need as many bpc as possible to achieve it...